# MediaWiki: check if current page is an article page

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm working on an extension for MediaWiki. I want to add a tab to the article pages only -- not for edit, history, talk or any other special page.

So far, I've achieved by checking that both the namespace (for "Special:whatever" pages) and the action GET parameter (for "?action=edit" pages) are blank, but I don't know if there's a better way of doing it.

```
if ($sktemplate -> getRequest() -> getText("action") == "" && 
    $sktemplate -> getTitle() -> getNsText() == ""){

    $links["namespaces"]["newbutton"] = array(
        "class" => "",
        "text" => "New button",
        "href" => "http://www.google.es",       
    );
}
```

As far as I know, the `Title` object has some methods, like `isTalkPage`, but I haven't found anything like `isNormalPage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to know whether it is a [content page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUsing_custom_namespaces#Content_namespaces), in which case you can use [$title->isContentPage()](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classTitle.html#a8cc2b58a5e8009a024131ef0185f4e49).